# How to calculate R-squared after using clogit function in R

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate the R-squared value of a logistic regression model using the `clogit` function after multiple imputations with mice package in R. Here's the code for the model:

```
fitt2 <- with(imp30, clogit(Prognosis ~ stromal_TILs + hair_follicles + Upward_scatter,  strata(Set_ID)))
summary(pool(fitt2), conf.int = TRUE, exponentiate = TRUE)
```

The `pool.r.squared()` by mice package seems to work only with `lm()`. How can I obtain the R-squared value of this model?

Comment: I voted to migrate this question to [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com) because R-squared is not a well-defined metric for conditional logit models.  There are several pseudo R-squared measures as well as other fit measures (e.g., the proportional reduction in error) that might work.  Which one to use and how to aggregate them across the imputations is a question that is beyond the programming purview of SO.